# how to link a file through a vba form in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I created a form that allows the user to click a button and then it allows you to browse and find your document or whatever and will submit it as a link with other related data. I'm wondering if their is a way to allow the user to make the link connect to a folder filled with multiple files without having them do it manually. Here is my code below

```
  Private Sub AddPicture_Click()
Dim strFileToLink As String

'link name
lnkNm = InputBox("please enter link description")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFileToLink = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please select an Evidence file to link to")

'Checking if file is selected.
If strFileToLink = "" Then
    'Displaying a message if file not choosen in the above step.
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry"
    'And exiting from the procedure.
    Exit Sub
Else
    'print link to sheet as a hyperlink.
    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ActiveSheet

        If ActiveSheet.Index >= 5 Then
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(erow, 12), _
            Address:=strFileToLink, _
            ScreenTip:="Picture Link", _
            TextToDisplay:=lnkNm

        Else
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(erow, 13), _
            Address:=strFileToLink, _
            ScreenTip:="Picture Link", _
            TextToDisplay:=lnkNm

        End If
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

comments on improving the code would be much appreciated as well. thank you

Comment: Link on the userform you mean? I am sorry, I didn't understand your requirement

Comment: I want the userform to let the user grab the folder/file and then link will be put on an excel sheet.

Comment: So what problem are you facing with the above code?

Comment: `GetOpenFileName` returns a file name, not a Folder name. I'd recommend the `FileDialog` object instead, you can use it for both purposes.

Comment: the code works fine but when I change  the     GetOpenFileName  to     FileDialog  it gives me a compile error saying named argument not found

Comment: You don't supply the `Title` as an argument to the `FileDialog` function, you set the `.Title` property *after* instantiating the object. See my answer below for implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Application.GetOpenFileName` use `Application.FileDialog`, which can be customized for Folders or Files, among other things.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx

Here is how you can use it to get a Folder Name OR a File Name:

```
Dim fdlg As FileDialog

Dim fdlgType as Long, itm as Variant
fdlgType = Application.InputBox("Enter '3' to choose a FILE, or '4' to choose a FOLDER")
If fdlgType < 3 or fdlgType > 4 Then Exit Sub
Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(fdlgType)
With fdlg
    .Title = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Please select an Evidence FILE to link to", _
                               "Please select an Evidence FOLDER to link to")
    .ButtonName = IIf(fdlgType = 3, "Select File", "Select Folder")
    .Show
    For Each itm in .SelectedItems
        MsgBox itm
    Next
End With
```

There is a `.AllowMultiSelect` property of the `FileDialog` which if True would let the user select multiple files (does not work on Folders). Then you can loop over the `.SelectedItems`.

In your code, then the `For Each itm` loop would contain the code which adds hyperlinks:

```
If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry"
    Exit Sub
End If
For Each itm in .SelectedItems
    'print link to sheet as a hyperlink.
    With ActiveSheet
        erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        If .Index >= 5 Then
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(erow, 12), _
            Address:=itm, _
            ScreenTip:="Picture Link", _
            TextToDisplay:=lnkNm

        Else
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(erow, 13), _
            Address:=itm, _
            ScreenTip:="Picture Link", _
            TextToDisplay:=lnkNm

        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: thank you after a little bit of tweaking it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using: -

```
Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select an evidence file to link to")
```

or even: -

```
Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select an evidence file to link to", MultiSelect:=True)
```

So that they can pick multiple files where you could add each as their own line item if needed.

I would recommend using: -

```
Application.FileDialog msoFileDialogFolderPicker
```

For folder selection, and: -

```
Application.FileDialog msoFileDialogFilePicker
```

For file selection, as you don't have an error and the question was: -

> I'm wondering if their is a way to allow the user to make the link connect to a folder filled with multiple files

The above information should be enough for you to alter your code as required, I would suggest having two buttons on your `UserForm`, 'Link File(s)' and 'Link Folder'.

If you do get errors while altering your code, feel free to post them (if you can't find an answer) and I'm sure people will help with your specific query.